# How to stop videoCapture() using node and openCV

Tags: node.js, opencv

I want to stop videoCaputure from Node.js. How can I do it?

```
var cv = require('opencv');
var camWidth = 640;
var camHeight = 480;
var camFps = 40;
var camInterval = 1000 / camFps;

camera = new cv.VideoCapture(0);
camera.setWidth(camWidth);
camera.setHeight(camHeight);

camera.read(function(err, im) {
   if (err) throw err;
   ...
}
```

Now, I want to stop videoCapture...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling release() ?
http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#afb4ab689e553ba2c8f0fec41b9344ae6

In your example it should be:

```
camera.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use time to stop your camera like this example

```
///stop camera after 10 seconds
function isTimerFinished(timeBeforeExecute) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    return (currentTime < timeBeforeExecute + 10)
}


 var timeBeforeExecute = new Date().getTime() / 1000; 


var video = setInterval(function () {

        if (isTimerFinished(timeBeforeExecute)) {
            const frame = wCap.read();
            const image = cv.imencode('.jpg', frame).toString('base64');
            io.emit('image', image)
        } else {
            image = '../public/img/image.jpg';
            io.emit('image', image)
            clearInterval(video);
        }

    }, 1000 / FPS);
```